# How much does the coordinate ring of a variety act like the overall polynomial ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety. Its coordinate ring $k[X]$ is a quotient of some overall polynomial ring $R$. With $R$, we can define algebraic varieties, the Zariski topology, etc. How much of that can we still do if we start with $k[X]$?

For example, we can look at the ideals of $k[X]$ and see their vanishing locii as subsets of $X$.  Do we still have:

- weak nullstellensatz?
- a correspondence between algebraic sets and radical ideals, between varieties and prime ideals, etc.?
- a Noetherian topology/Noetherian domain?

It would be a tedious (though maybe informative) exercise to go through all of the results in my course notes and check that they still hold for $k[X]$. But is there a simpler way? Am I missing some obvious way to do this, or some place where this fails?

Comment: All of the things you ask should be very straightforward (either from the definitions or from the correspondence theorem for ideals). What have you tried?

Comment: I showed that ideals in $k[X]$ are of the form $J+I(X)$ for ideals $J$ in the overall ring, which gives a lot of the results fairly easily. But this seems rather ad hoc. Is there not some deeper correspondence?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the [right correspondence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813978/correspondence-theorem-for-rings)? This should make things clearer.