# Maximal ideals in $R/I$ for $R$ a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and $I \subseteq R$ any ideal.

Is it true that the maximal ideals of $R/I$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the maximal ideals of $R$ which contain $I$?

Comment: Yes. That's part of te all-powerful and important Correspondence Theorem for rings. There is also one for groups.

Comment: If you upgrade your comment to an answer then I will happily accept it so that this question can be listed as answered :)

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813978/correspondence-theorem-for-rings) is related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is part of the all-powerful and important Correspondence Theorem for rings. The is also a Correspondence Theorem for groups.